# Tiling/Caching with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, tiles, cache, image-service

A few weeks ago we crashed our server by trying to tile a large image service (600gbs) (multiple times without clearing the cache) which caused us to exceed the servers free disk space.

We fixed the issue by deleting the service and clearing the server cache.  From this point forward we have not been able to publish and tile an image service, however we are able to publish a regular map service.

Does anyone know what might be causing us to not be able to publish/tile image services?

Is there a potential break in code somewhere in a config file on the server?

We are running ArcGIS 10.1 and we have substantial free disk space.

Comment: does the server user still have access to the cache location?

Comment: Yes, when we go through the publishing process we either get an error that says 'packaging succeeded but publishing failed' or we get 'publishing succeeded' but in either case a cache file is created on the server it just doesn't progress from there.

Answer (score 3):

Check the server cache directory. with...
http://mygisserver.com/arcgis/admin/system/directories/arcgiscache
Ensure it is registered with the server.

Make sure the cache geoprocessing service is running.
[image: cache geoprocessing]

You might also check the jobs folder to see if there is something hung up there.
http://mygisserver.com/arcgis/admin/system/jobs

Also check the status of the [cache job with this report](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewing_cache_completion_status/0154000005p9000000/).
I would certainly suggest getting to the bottom of this issue, but a workaround for now may be to use the [export import options.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_and_importing_map_caches/0154000003sq000000/)

You haven't said anything about it being a shared cache so I would expect [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Local_cache_directories_on_the_server/01540000046r000000/) to be the problem or issue.

Next I would look into the logs.
Set your log level to verbose (temporarily).
Send a new cache job and view the log codes.
The caching all happens in the [geoprocessing service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geoprocessing_service_log_codes/0154000005v7000000/) so check the log codes for that.

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks so much for your help above you definitely pointed us in the right direction.  We are back up and caching now but I have a follow up question for you.  If we are caching something with a single band ie LiDAR everything goes smoothly, however when we try to post something with 3 bands like aerial imagery we get the message "packaging succeeded publishing failed" any ideas?

Comment: that's confusing. not sure why a single band image would be any different than any other image file. are the images in a gdb? are they uploading to the server? if not Be certain the ags server account (the one running in the service) has access to the location. AND the location is configured as a data folder. Are the rgbs stored in the same place as the lidar? provide some more info about how you are publishing. screen shots of each page. (blank propr info)